# swift - Mapkit changing pinTintColor in if else statement

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to change pin colour based on a variable - the colour of certain pins change but it seems random and doesn't relate to the colour that I'm expecting. I suspect it's something to do with dequeueReusableAnnotationView.I have tried without but I got the same results. Any ideas ? Thanks

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

     let identifier = "Annotation"
     var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

        pin.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView = pin

        if globalDataSet[counter].fields.numdocksavailable == 0 {

            print (counter,globalDataSet[counter].fields.numdocksavailable, globalDataSet[counter].fields.name)
            print ("pin.pinTintColor = UIColor.systemBlue")
            pin.pinTintColor = UIColor.systemBlue
            

        } else {
            print (counter,globalDataSet[counter].fields.numdocksavailable, globalDataSet[counter].fields.name)
            print ("pin.pinTintColor = UIColor.systemRed")
            pin.pinTintColor = UIColor.systemRed
            
        }
        
        counter += 1

    } else {

        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
if annotationView == nil {
    let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

    pin.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView = pin
    

} else {

    annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    
}

if globalDataSet[counter].fields.numdocksavailable == 0 {

    print (counter,globalDataSet[counter].fields.numdocksavailable, globalDataSet[counter].fields.name)
    print ("annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.systemBlue")
    annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        

} else {
    print (counter,globalDataSet[counter].fields.numdocksavailable, globalDataSet[counter].fields.name)
    print ("annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.systemRed")
    annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.systemRed
        
}

counter += 1
```

Comment: hey - thanks for answering - unfortunately this gives me the error value of type annotationView has no member pintintcolor and so doesn't build - I managed to get it to build by moving "let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)" and changing to pin.pinTintColor = but still no luck.